# prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: exit status 1 in docker

Tags: docker, centos6

I was trying to install docker on a centos 6 64bit with kernel 3.18.21-17.el6.x86_64 by following [this tutorial](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/docker-centos-6-and-you/). But i am getting this error when i am starting the docker daemon.

```
[root@test docker]# docker -d
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: exit status 1
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: exit status 1
```

Here are some more inputs:

```
[root@test docker]# docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

[root@test docker]# uname -r
3.18.21-17.el6.x86_64

[root@test docker]# service docker start
Starting docker:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@test docker]# service docker status
docker dead but subsys locked

[root@test docker]# docker -d -D
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /auth
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /build
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /commit
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/create
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/load
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/create
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}
DEBU[0000] Registering OPTIONS,
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /info
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /version
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/ps
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /_ping
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /events
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/json
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/get
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/search
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/json
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws
DEBU[0000] devicemapper: driver version is 4.28.0
DEBU[0000] Generated prefix: docker-8:2-394662
DEBU[0000] Checking for existence of the pool 'docker-8:2-394662-pool'
DEBU[0000] [deviceset] constructDeviceIdMap()
DEBU[0000] Loading data for file /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata/base
DEBU[0000] Added deviceId=1 to DeviceIdMap
DEBU[0000] Loading data for file /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata/transaction-metadata
DEBU[0000] Added deviceId=1 to DeviceIdMap
DEBU[0000] [deviceset] constructDeviceIdMap() END
DEBU[0000] Removing uninitialized base image
DEBU[0000] activateDeviceIfNeeded()
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 495
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
DEBU[0000] [devmapper] removeDevice START(docker-8:2-394662-base)
DEBU[0000] [devmapper] removeDevice END(docker-8:2-394662-base)
DEBU[0000] unregisterDevice(1, )
DEBU[0000] Initializing base device-mapper thin volume
DEBU[0000] [devmapper] CreateDevice(poolName=/dev/mapper/docker-8:2-394662-pool, deviceId=1)
DEBU[0000] Registering device (id 1) with FS size 10737418240
DEBU[0000] registerDevice(1, )
DEBU[0000] Creating filesystem on base device-mapper thin volume
DEBU[0000] activateDeviceIfNeeded()
DEBU[0000] Error device setupBaseImage: exit status 1
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: exit status 1
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: exit status 1
```

i am feeling like i have missed some configurations related to docker.

```
[root@test docker]# cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
# /etc/sysconfig/docker
#
# Other arguments to pass to the docker daemon process
# These will be parsed by the sysv initscript and appended
# to the arguments list passed to docker -d

other_args=""
```

I have to stick to Centos 6.Could you please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: First of all, I'd try to install docker 1.7.1 (not 1.7.0), which is the [last supported version for CentOS 6](http://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/6/Packages/); it contains some bug fixes. Is this a first time install, or an upgrade? If it's a first-time install, you could consider wiping `/var/lib/docker` because it looks like it contains data from previous attempts. You **will** loose all containers/images present locally  though.

Comment: Also make sure you read the storage-driver section on devicemapper, because the default ("loop-lvm") configuration is not intended for production use, and results in bad performance; https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/

Comment: @thaJeztah It is a first time install. and i have already tried wiping /var/lib/docker directory and still getting the same error. I have docker 1.7.1 installed in another box which is also giving the same error. Thanks for your response.

Comment: How did you install docker? Did you use the yum repository, or did you install a static binary? Alternatively, you could have a look at Oracle Linux 6, which is still actively supported https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/oracle/

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Docker 1.7.1 solved the 'docker dead but subsys locked' issue for Redhat_6.7 Release for me.